# SQL Query txt file named currentdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, date, time

in brief

That:

```
bulk insert Table
from '**C:\PATH\ currentdate_time.txt**'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
```

is what i want to do in MSSQL.

example : `13.03.2014_15:18.txt`

Comment: Eh? Surely you have to know the file name before you go in? Current date and time seem to have nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Colon `:` isn't a legal part of file names.

Comment: On that note YYYYMMDDHHMM.txt would be a far more useful format as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @sql = 'Bulk insert ' + @Table + ' from ''' + @file + ''' with (fieldterminator = '','', rowterminator = ''\\n'')'

Exec(@sql)
```

`@Table` and what `@File` would have to come in as arguments, say to a Stored Proc, or a statement.